# Number of $(2n-1)$-edge-colorings of the complete graph $K_{2n}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

I just started reading about graph theory and have a question (which might be trivial). How many $(2n-1)$ edge colorings of $K_{2n}$ are there?

A vaguer question: can I write $K_{4n}= K_4 + K_4 +.....+K_4$ where each $K_4$ has a 3-edge coloring considered as a subgraph of $K_n$? More generally, what's a good reference for edge-colorings of complete graphs.

thanks

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000438

Comment: If you want non-isomorphic ones: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/garnick.pdf